# HTML-elements added by jQuery get lost on post-back

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I'm developing a simple web page in ASP.NET and I use jQuery too. On my page there is a form with a table which contains several text boxes in each row. When the page is loaded there is only one row with empty textboxes visible. Now if the user enters any text in the last row, I add another row below the last row using jQuery. I simply clone the last row, rename it and add it to the table using the 'insertAfter' function. This works perfectly fine but there are two problems:

1. When I submit the form (using a button), validity of the input is checked using ASP.NET. If there is some invalid input, I show an error message at the rightmost end of each row. The problem is, that all rows added by jQuery get lost and disappear in this case, including all contents of the textboxes. Is there any solution for this problem?
2. The submit button is directly under the first row, after the page is loaded. If I add a row to the table using jQuery then the button gets covered by the table. What could I do to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now. The solution for me is to use AJAX and call a ASP.NET Webservice which does the validation like it is described here: [ASP.NET Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1934215.aspx?Using%20jQuery%20ajax%20to%20call%20asmx%20webservice%20methods)

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1 is happening because your validation is server side and written in C# rather than client side. Because you're dynamically adding objects to the page (using jQuery) the C# .net code you're using to validate doesn't know what these are, thus are destoyed when the postback completes it's validation.

The solution is to pull all the validation client side and do it in jQuery. You can use the validate plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for example.

The second issue is a CCS one. You should split the table and the button up and put them in separate div tags. Then as the size of the table increases inside it's container the other container with the button is pushed down the screen rather than just overwritten.

Comment: Issue 2 was caused by the absolute position of the table, but it is solved now. I know what causes the first issue but validating input client side isn't a good idea in my opinion and an anti-pattern.